# How to get the Scope_identity value for the parent record using VS19 with bound datasets

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, scope-identity

I have two tables in MSSQL which are related `tbl1.PK` `tbl2.PK`, `tbl2FK(_tbl1PK)`

I have created a dataset in Visual Studio and they show up with the relation
when I drop the tables as datagrids onto a form I get the parentDG and childDG.
VS adds in the binding navigator which adds the save procedure

```
tbl1.bindingsource.endedit
tableadaptermanager.updateall
```

When I add data to the parentDG and press save the data gets saved to the DB.
When I add a new parent and then add a new child details and press save I get

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblChild_tblParent". The conflict occurred in database "xxxxx", table "dbo.tblParent", column 'PK'.

I have tried updating the `parentTableadapter` and then `ds.acceptchanges` but I can not get the new child row to update.

I understand why but my questions are:

- isn't the VS IDE supposed to handle this?
- if isn't for me so I presume I need to get the new `tbl1PK` (scope_identity).

I can see in the dataset code the insert command:

```
Me._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [] FROM tbl1 WHERE (PK= SCOPE_IDENTITY())"
```

BUT I cannot for the life of me see how to get this value.
I have a lot of tables with a lot of columns which is why I want/need to use the power of the IDE to populate and bind my controls and so I really do not want to go down the route of manually creating my datasets.

I have searched and searched on this and can't find anything that speaks to how you do this using VS auto generated code.

thanks

John

Comment: You need to include a `SELECT` statement after your `INSERT`, in the same command, which selects the new ID back into the parent `DataTable`.  If you have set up your `DataRelation` correctly, that value will be automatically propagated to the child `DataTable`.

Comment: So do i add this to query in the ds designer window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested and the addition of the query in the `InsertCommand` happened automatically so you must not have done something properly.  Here's EXACTLY what I did:

1. Created a new database named Test on my local default SQL Server instance via SSMS.
2. Added a table named Parent with columns ParentId (int, PK, identity) and ParentName (varchar).
3. Added a table named Child with columns ChildId (int, PK, identity), ParentId (int) and ChildName (varchar).
4. Created a foreign key in the Child table to the ParentId column from the ParentId column in the Parent table, setting the Update Rule to Cascade.
5. Created a new VB Windows Forms application project.
6. Added a new Data Source via the Data Sources window for the Test database.
7. Opened the TestDataSet from the Solution Explorer in the DataSet designer.
8. Selected the DataRelation between the two DataTables.
9. In the Properties window, clicked Edit Relation.
10. Checked 'Both Relation and Foreign Key Constraint', when Update Rule changed automatically to Cascade.

At this point, but even after step 7, I was able to select the ParentTableAdapter in the designer, expand the InsertCommand and view the CommandText to see this:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Parent] ([ParentName]) VALUES (@ParentName);
SELECT ParentId, ParentName FROM Parent WHERE (ParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

If you don't see that, you can set it yourself.  What happens now is that, when the InsertCommand is executed to insert a new record, that query immediately retrieves the data from that record back into the DataRow in your DataSet.  That will update the ParentId column with the newly generated value and the Update Rule will cause that new value to cascade to any related DataRows in the Child DataTable, so you can just go ahead and insert them without worry.

Comment: Thanks,  i have done the same as you but i'm stuck as to how to call the INSERT command.  When i ....endedit on the binding source what then do i call?  tableadaptermanager.updateall causes the FK problem.. If i've inderstood your suggestion i should be looking for something like i=tblParentAdapter.insertcommand

Comment: You haven't understood my suggestion. Whether or not `UpdateAll` works depends on how it is implemented, which you can see for yourself if you open the appropriate code file. For every scenario to work correctly, parent records must be inserted before child records and child records must be deleted before parent records. I don't know whether a table adapter manager does that or not. Check that first. Are you sure that you have configured the `DataRelation` as a foreign key that cascades on update? It's useless getting the parent ID if you don't propagate that to the child record(s).

Comment: I have checked the code file and the insert command is as you suggest.

Comment: On far too many occasions, I have seen people say "yes it is correct" when in fact it wasn't.  Instead of saying that it is as I expect it to be, tell me how it is and then I can be the judge.  If the table adapter manager and the `DataRelation` were configured as I expect then it would work, so obviously something is not as I expect.

Comment: I have checked the code file and the insert command is as you suggest.  I haven't explicitly done anything with the relation in VS.  I created the tables with PK and FK in sql and added a relationship.  i then added the dataset in VS and dragged the tables onto the form.  the child has a datamember that references the FK form the parent table.  If i add a new parent record then save that when i click on a new row in the chld it does correctly insert the FK id as you would expect.  So my question is how to save the parent?

Comment: DO i need to catch an event when the user leaves the parent and adds a new row tot the child and save the parent then or is VS setup to allow me to create a new parent row and new child rows and save them all in sequence?  if its the latter what save/update command do i run for the parent because it throws and error when i updateall in the tablemanageradapter.  thanks

Comment: Me._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblSupplierQuoteDetails] ([SupplierQuoteID], [PartNo], [Units]) VALUES (@SupplierQuoteID, @PartNo, @Units);"&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13)&Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)&
"SELECT SuppQoteDetailID, SupplierQuoteID, PartNo, Units FROM tblSupplierQuoteDetails WHERE (SuppQoteDetailID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())"

Comment: Please tell me what other code i can provide to help diagnose this. many thanks John

Comment: I can confirm that when i add a new parent and save the parent i can then add child records and the FK populates correctly.  What i can not do ia add a new parent and a new child and then use .UPDATEALL to save both.  the child record throws a missing FK exception.  I can not see how to call the INSERT command for the parent without updating the dataset. if i have to save the parent before the user starts adding children then what happens if a user decides to cancel the whole operation?

Comment: IT WORKS.  My thanks for your patience.  I had set the update cascade on the database but not on the dataset so you are right i did not follow steps 8-10, although I thought I did.  My apologies for taking up your time and thanks once again for your help.

Comment: This works perfectly when you have two datagrids on the form but when i change the parent to individual text boxes i get an exception saying the FK is missing for the child record.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest that you post that as a new question and provide all the information specific to it.

Comment: ok thanks and thanks once again for your help getting me this far